# How to keep my cursor focus when switching of workspace if I have a fullscreened window on another screen?

Tags: debian, gnome, workspaces, fullscreen

Let's say I have,

On **screen 1**:

- ***workspace A***: a web browser, extended (not full-screened with F11, just maxed out).
- ***workspace B***: a terminal with Vi for example.

On **screen 2**:

- a web browser, full-screened.

When I switch, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>or<kbd>↓</kbd>, from ***workspace A*** to ***workspace B*** on **screen 1**, my cursor switch to **screen 2** *if, and only if, I have something full-screened.*

I lose my cursor focus and it's annoying when I'm editing a file with Vi, while watching a video in full screen on my second screen, check something on chrome and go back to my Vi instance as what I type is now typed on my chrome instance on my other screen.

Is it possible to force my cursor to stay on my first screen when I have a full-screened window in my second screen?

I'm on `Debian Jessie` and `Gnome 3`.

Comment: I think this feature would have supported to the window manager (otherwise there's likely to be a visible delay between switching workspaces and moving the cursor). Which window manager are you using? Are you prepared to change? Gnome typically favors a lack of flexibility, and for example I doubt that Metacity has anything close to what you want, but there are window managers that you can use with Gnome where you can add this feature with a few lines of code in your configuration file, e.g. Sawfish.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't too much of a fix as it is an annoyance minimizer, but in System->Preferences->Monitors, drag the 2nd monitor to the edge so that they only touch corners. Theoretically, that means it'll only transfer over if you pull the mouse into a corner. On the Debian/Gentoo Wiki, they posted a small program that might work also. Good luck my man